Why does debug printing an env_logger::Builder show "Logger { ... }"?
My test code produces this debug output:
use env_logger::Builder;

fn main() {
    let mut builder = Builder::new();
    println!("{:?}", builder);
}

Logger { filter: Filter { filter: None, directives: [] }, writer: Builder { target: stderr, write_style: Auto, is_test: false, built: false } }

Why is it printed as a Logger instead of a Builder struct?
I can see that Builder::new() will return the Builder struct in the logger.rs source:
#[derive(Default)]
pub struct Builder {
    filter: env_filter::Builder,
    writer: writer::Builder,
    format: fmt::Builder,
    built: bool,
}
impl Builder {
    pub fn new() -> Builder {
        Default::default()
    }
}

Why debug print result is Logger struct?

Because the manual Debug implementation for Builder pretends it was a Logger.
